# Clone macro in LibreOffice Base

Tags: grid, libreoffice, radix, subform, libreoffice-basic

I have a clone macro in a subform table control grid which copies 1 row to a clone table.
It works perfectly if only 1 record. If another record is added, it still just copies the first.
If there are many records and none have been copied and then the macro is run, it will copy
the first record. If macro is run again, it will copy last record.If records are clicked on
is no help. Does anyone know of additional code to be able to make any specific record the active record??

```vb
Sub Clone_To_New_Record (oEvent As Object) 'Button > Execute > event
        oForm = oEvent.Source.Model.Parent 'SubForm from Button 
        IF oForm.isNew THEN Exit Sub
    oForm.updateRow
        iID = oForm.Columns.GetByName("EX").Value
    oForm.moveToInsertRow
    oStatement = oForm.ActiveConnection.createStatement() 'Create an SQL statement object       
    sColumns = sColumns & """EX"""
    sColumns = sColumns & ", ""ID2"""
    sColumns = sColumns & ", ""DESCRIBE"""
        sColumns = sColumns & ", ""AMOUNT"""
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO ""CLONE2"" (" & sColumns & ") SELECT " & sColumns & " FROM ""EXPLAIN"" WHERE ""EX"" = " 
        & iID
    oStatement.executeUpdate( sSQL ) 'Execute the SQL command
    oForm.reload
    oForm.last
End Sub
```

I have looked at various posts that seem to be what I want,
but either none worked or I put them in the wrong place.
They all brought up various problems, but I don't know how
to address them.

Comment: Welcome! If you want to clone all records of a table, then you should not restrict the selection of records with `WHERE ""EX"" = " & iID`. If you don't want a lot of duplicate records every time you run a macro, then clear the table or re-create it before writing. But to be honest, your question is taken out of context, the task that you have set and that you are trying to solve [**is not clear**](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I will try to clarify the problem.
This is, of course, a one to many situation. It is from an
inventory database where the main form has customer info,
and the sub form, on the grid, has the individual items purchased.
I was trying to run the macro as each item was added to a clone table.
I suppose adding them all at once at the end would work also.
As it stands now, it only works correctly if there is only one item.  
I was thinking I needed some additional code for that. Could you help.
Thanks,  Walt

Comment: No, no, the purpose of the macro was clear from its code. The purpose of the clone table remained unclear - why duplicate entries as you fill out the order form? And what happens if the operator made a mistake (the erroneous entry got into the clones), deleted the erroneous line and entered a new one (the erroneous entry remained in the clone table)? Why do you need a clone table at all, if you can get all the necessary product records with a query?